# Rollup deepmerge include classes that extend from abstract in bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollup

I have a abstract class called Module

```
export abstract class Module {
    protected scriptConfig: GM_configStruct;

    constructor(config: GM_configStruct) {
        this.scriptConfig = config;
    }

    abstract getModuleInfo(): ModuleInfo;
    abstract register(): void;
    abstract deRegister(): void;
    abstract update(): void;
}

export namespace Module {
    type Constructor<T> = {
        new (scriptConfig: GM_configStruct): T;
        readonly prototype: T;
    };
    const implementations: Constructor<Module>[] = [];
    export function getImplementations(): Constructor<Module>[] {
        return implementations;
    }
    export function register<T extends Constructor<Module>>(ctor: T) {
        implementations.push(ctor);
        return ctor;
    }
}

export interface ModuleInfo {
    activeUrl: string;
}
```

and subclasses that inherit from there. For example this TestModule

```
import { ScriptConfigField } from "../utils/ScriptConfigField";
import { Module, ModuleInfo } from "../Module";

export default class TestModule extends Module {
    getModuleInfo(): ModuleInfo {
        return {
            activeUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        };
    }

    register(): void {
        console.log("Test module registered", this.scriptConfig.get(ScriptConfigField.DarkModeOptimized));
    }

    update(): void {
        console.log("update test module");
    }

    deRegister(): void {}
}
```

I bundle this with rollup and deepmerge:

```
import merge from "deepmerge";
import { createBasicConfig } from "@open-wc/building-rollup";

// set developmentMode to true because it disables the minifing of the code
const baseConfig = createBasicConfig({ developmentMode: true });

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  input: ["./build/tsc/sources/scriptHub/ScriptHub.user.js", "./build/tsc/sources/eventHub/EventHub.user.js"],
  output: {
    dir: "./build/scripts"
  }
});
```

but since the TestModule is nowhere referenced in the code itself it doesn't get included in the bundle. But it needs to that I can access it via the getImplementations() function on the Module. I somehow need to include the TestModule file and all other in /modules in the bundle